# How to represent Android BluetoothCallback in UML classdiagram?

Tags: android, bluetooth, callback, uml, class-diagram

How do i represent the following piece of code in a classdiagram?

```
public class BluetoothClass{

public BluetoothClass(){
}

private final BluetoothGattCallback btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        //do something
    }
    @Override
    public void onReadRemoteRssi(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);
       //do something
    }
};
}
```

Should i represent it as just an innerclass?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is a property and you should show it as such. Simply add a property named btleGattCallback  of type `BluetoothGattCallback`. You could go ahead and create an object diagram (which is sort of a class diagram but for instances) and there nest the `BluetoothGattCallback` object inside an instance of `BluetoothClass`.